# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' , What should I do to fix it?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have written the CSV using the following code snippet. What is wrong in it?

```
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text","retweet_count","favorite_count"])
  writer.writerows(outtweets)
```

Comment: Where does outtweets come from? include your full stack trace in your post.

Comment: why did you open in `'wb'` mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error message, you're using Python 3 and not Python 2. When you open a file in binary mode with the `'b'` flag, you're saying you'll write bytes to it and *not* strings. Leave off the `b` in the mode flag to `open` and you should be fine.